# Swift Data support to NSExpression

Tags: core-data, swift-data

Does swiftData support NSExpression or any way to do min/max and sum operations. Like in coreCata ,

```
let keypathExp1 = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "col")
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [keypathExp1])
```